# How to revisit a Stack Overflow ad

Tags: support, stack-overflow, advertising

Is there a place where I can see all the ads listed in SO?

When I was reading a question, I liked an ad, then quickly hit the back button. When I hit the forward button, the ad had changed.

Is there a way I can see the ads for a given tag or something?

Comment: This is a fantastic feature request. Double-plus-good

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's starting to sound like Jeff & Co. need to build an ad gallery.

Then you could put more ads in the gallery! **$$$$$$$$$$$$$$**

Comment: **`1.`** Build ad gallery. **`2.`** Profit!

Comment: This would be very beneficial...

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/ Now, how do I profit?

Comment: Any idea why @perbert's link was deleted?

Comment: Ha. The above 'ad gallery' link is dead. Only Stackoverflow would remove a page that showcases their advertisers to people that actually *want* to see ads. So disrespectful to the advertisers that paid you.

Answer (score 11):

You could always refresh a whole bunch of times to see that ad... I'm kidding, please don't do that ;-)

But, we were thinking of putting together a "sponsor gallery" of sorts that listed out all of the sponsors with a brief description. Kinda in the vein of what we have on the every-now-and-then sponsor appreciation posts at TDWTF: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Sponsor-Appreciation,-Emptiness,-Empty-Support--More.aspx

There are some pretty cool companies that sponsor the sites.

Comment: If you weren't aware, this guy is actually the Ad Manager (or whatever you want to call him) for SO/SF/SU

Comment: Ahh... I knew i'd seen that name *somewhere* before!

Comment: @Tom, I actually prefer "Ad Sultan". Though, for some reason, "the ad guy" has stuck.

Answer (score 6):

My greatest pet peeve about online advertisement is relevance - I'm not interested in 99.9 percent 
of the ads I see (although the relevance is a bit higher on the trilogy, IMO).

My second greatest pet peeve is that I can't get back to the 0.1 percent of ads I'm interested in, because I already clicked a link or hit the back button, and I happened to see one out of the corner of my eye while the browser was refreshing.

AARRGGGH!

Comment: I'll take this as another "ping" to get the sponsor gallery going: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that

Answer (score 0):

You could visit the [Unofficial Meta Stack Overflow Stack Overflow Ad Gallery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/). If it's not there, it would be greatly appreciated if you could add it at a later time.

Comment: Dead link now; has the post moved or is the list completely dead?

Comment: @sarnold: `deleted by Jeff Atwood♦ Jan 28 '11 at 6:58`. There seems to have been a big change in the ad serving server, so most, if not all, the images linked ceased to work.