# Search ads for past ad

Tags: feature-request, search, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sponsor Gallery, Page, or Something Like That?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that)

I just saw an ad right before refreshing the page, and would like to get back to it. I recall some of the wording, and would love to be able to simply input that into a textbox, be given some results, and score SO some cash.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that

Comment: So far, this is the closest thing to what you are asking for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/