# Searchable list of Adverts

Tags: feature-request, advertising

The SE network serves adverts for revenue, but they have been kind enough to make them non-obtrusive and on-topic. I have actually found 2 tools that I now use in production via these adverts. So kudos!

But, sometimes what happens is that you notice an interesting advert just as you hit refresh and then it is gone. Or you are on a new browser instance/machine and forgotten to turn the ad-blocker off.

Why not have a list of the adverts somewhere and searchable. I know I wouldn't mind looking at it once in a while. You will also get some additional click-through revenue from there.

Again it is non-obtrusive and a user has to navigate to and thus opt-in to view the page - so no harm done.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14442/how-to-revisit-a-stack-overflow-ad http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78777/is-there-a-list-of-all-ads-that-appeared-on-stackoverflow  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/search-ads-for-past-ad

Answer (score 5):

It's an interesting idea, but likely more work than you'd expect. It's not a matter of just showing a gallery of image files for several reasons.

Reasons I can think of off hand:

- We sometimes let the advertiser render their own ad at page-load time, and it's unclear whether they would want this happening outside of a *real* ad since it may alter their analytics.
- Some advertisers wouldn't want to be included in a gallery because they only want to reach a certain audience.
- Our display advertising is through AdZerk right now, which means we'd have to interface with their api to try to get this data.
- To be useful, we'd likely have to support some sort of search or group-by-tag functionality.

I like the idea, and think that it's a bit analogous to the advertising index you find at the back of magazines, I'm just skeptical of the effort/usefulness ratio. I'll keep it in mind, and maybe someday, but no promises.

I'm very happy you find the ads useful and unobtrusive, though.