# Is there a list of all ads that appeared on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, advertising

I wanted to email one of these ads to a friend, but I don't remember the exact phrasing / how to Google for it. It was something in the spirit of "we hire monkeys, so you don't need to".

Answer (score 1):

There used to be one here:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/

but apparently that one is deleted.

Why's that? Can anybody with 10K+ maybe see on that question why it has been removed?

There's also this one:

> [Sponsor Gallery, Page, or Something Like That?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that)

in which one mr. Alex 'advertisement' Papadingsken himself proposes to create such a list.