# I saw an ad now I can't find it

Tags: feature-request, support, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revisit ad in Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14442/how-to-revisit-ad-in-stackoverflow)

So I was answering a question.  Saw an ad that looked interesting -- figured I would click on that when I'm done with this answer.

It was gone after the post.  Now I can't get it to show up.  Is there any place I can go to see all the ads on the site so I can find it again?

Comment: Just keep refreshing. The ad gallery idea is pretty much dead, unless you'll put bounty on that other question but I doubt even that will be enough.