# Show me the same Advertisement when I hit back?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising

Quite often I'll see something interesting in the Advertising square on the right side of the screen just as I navigate away from the page. I hit the back button so I can click on it, but the ad has been switched to something else.

Would it be possible to make the advertisement persist so when I hit the Back button, I get the same ad that was just there?

Comment: So I'm not the only one... I'm grateful for Mobile Safari in this scenario - the back button does the "right thing".

Comment: This same issue [has been discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14442/how-to-revisit-ad-in-stackoverflow), and [Robert Harvey agrees with you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24102/153008). I have the same problem, I just never care enough to click the "back" button.

Comment: It's pretty hard to make this work across browsers -- they all refresh assets based on different rules.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest a technically simpler solution for this would be a means to see all ads and/or to search for an ad.  It isn't necessarily that you need to see the same ad when you use the back button, but rather that you'd like to find an ad that was on a previous page.

Comment: Some "smarts" could even be added in based on time, showing "more recent" ads near the top of a list or something similar.

Comment: As long as it includes the questions from other SE sites, I'll be happy :)

Comment: You'd think The Team would want to make it easy for us to see all their supporters...